# Enum в CSharp

Tags: java, c#

Доброго времени суток!

В языке Java, используя перечисления(enum), можно в них добавлять свои методы:

```
enum Type {
    INT(true) {
        public Object parse(String string) { return Integer.valueOf(string); }
    },
    INTEGER(false) {
        public Object parse(String string) { return Integer.valueOf(string); }
    },
    STRING(false) {
        public Object parse(String string) { return string; }
    };

    boolean primitive;
    Type(boolean primitive) { this.primitive = primitive; }

    public boolean isPrimitive() { return primitive; }
    public abstract Object parse(String string);
}
```

Пытаясь проделать такое в C#, я получаю ошибку компиляции. Я что-то не так делаю или эта возможность не реализована в Шарпе?

Всем известно, что C# и Java как языки программирования во многом схожи, именно поэтому и провожу аналогию, для более подробного описания вопроса. Я не прошу вас и не хочу сам их сравнивать, а точнее выяснять какой лучше, так что пож. не нужно этого делать.

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В C# такая возможность отсутствует: `enum`-ы это не более чем типизированный набор констант, с возможностью использовать его как набор флагов, для которого определены методы в [классе](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.enum.aspx) `Enum`.

Допускается иметь значения полей перечислимого типа со значением, не определённым в самом типе, например:

```
enum Foo
{
    First,
    Second,
    Third,
}

// в методе:
// не вызывает ни ошибок компиляции,
// ни ошибок выполнения
Foo foo = (Foo)1234;
```

Как вариант, можно получить схожее поведение описанием методов в статическом классе:

```
static class FooHelper
{
    public static object Parse(Foo type, string value)
    {
        switch (type)
        {
            case Foo.First:
                // ...
                break;
            // ...
            default:
                throw new ArgumentException("type must be valid value from Foo.");
        }
    }
}
```